# How to use str_split with regex in R?

Tags: r, regex, stringr, strsplit

I have this string:

```
235072,testing,some252f4,14084-things224072,and,other2524,14084-thingies223552,testing,some/2wr24,14084-things
```

I want to split the string by the 6-digit numbers. I.e. - I want this:

```
235072,testing,some2wg2f4,wf484-things
224072,and,other25wg4,14-thingies
223552,testing,some/2wr24,14084-things
```

How do I do this with regex? The following does not work (using `stringr` package):

```
> blahblah <- "235072,testing,some252f4,14084-things224072,and,other2524,14084-thingies223552,testing,some/2wr24,14084-things"
> test <- str_split(blahblah, "([0-9]{6}.*)")
> test
[[1]]
[1] "" ""
```

What am I missing??

Comment: By using `.*` in your regex you're allowing to it match anything. So the split regex expands to the whole length of your string, and then when you split either side of that you end up with two empty strings at the start and end.

Comment: Thanks! That fixed the problem. However, I just realized I have some 7 digit numbers screwing things up. You have a way to exclude 7 digit numbers, but keep parsing by the 6 digits??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An alternative approach with `str_extract_all`. Note I've used `.*?` to do 'non-greedy' matching, otherwise `.*` expands to grab everything:

```
> str_extract_all(blahblah, "[0-9]{6}.*?(?=[0-9]{6}|$)")[[1]]
[1] "235072,testing,some252f4,14084-things"  "224072,and,other2524,14084-thingies"    "223552,testing,some/2wr24,14084-things"
```

Comment: I actually used this solution, since it seems to work much better with my very large string (49MB). However, how would I now adjust it to accept either 6 or 3 digit (but not any other amount) integers as the delimiters?

Comment: This works`str_extract_all(mystring, "[0-9]*.*?(?=\\s{5}[0-9]{3}|\\s{5}[0-9]{6}|$)")`, but it adds an empty string after every real string, so I get twice as many results. Any ideas why?

Comment: GOT IT! This works perfectly - `str_extract_all(mystring, "(\\d{6}|\\d{3}).*?(?=\\s{5}[0-9]{3}|\\s{5}[0-9]{6}|$)")[[1]]`    Thanks for everyone's help!

Comment: I think because you have only `*` ("zero or more") and lookaheads in that one, it allows for a zero-length match at the point where the lookahead matches. It's hard to work this stuff out in comments though, might be best to write a new question with clear examples of the new problem (should be fine as long as you have good examples making clear how it's  different to this one).

Answer (score 5):

Here's an approach with base R using a positive lookahead and lookbehind, and thanks to @thelatemail for the correction:

```
strsplit(x, "(?<=.)(?=[0-9]{6})", perl = TRUE)[[1]]
# [1] "235072,testing,some252f4,14084-things"  
# [2] "224072,and,other2524,14084-thingies"    
# [3] "223552,testing,some/2wr24,14084-things"
```

Comment: Thanks! Goddamnit I hate regex. You recommend any good intros?? Every time i think I get it, I end up here...

Comment: Your solution cuts off the last character of the first two lines. Why that be?

Comment: @lukehawk, the problem was that those last characters were being used for splits. As for intros, I'm not sure.. Practicing and answering questions here works well.

Comment: @lukehawk, for your new problem try `strsplit(x, "(?<=\\D)(?=[0-9]{6}\\D)", perl = TRUE)[[1]]`.

Comment: Thanks Julius - I did not know it would matter, but this string is super big, about 50MB. I have switched to the `str_extract_all` solution, as it seems to be able to handle the large string much better.

Answer (score 0):

An easy-to-understand approach is to add a marker and then split on the locations of those markers. This has the advantage of being able to only look for 6-digit sequences and not require any other features in the surrounding text, whose features may change as you add new and unvetted data.

```
library(stringr)
library(magrittr)

str <- "235072,testing,some252f4,14084-things224072,and,other2524,14084-thingies223552,testing,some/2wr24,14084-things"

out <- 
    str_replace_all(str, "(\\d{6})", "#SPLIT_HERE#\\1") %>% 
    str_split("#SPLIT_HERE#") %>% 
    unlist

[1] ""                                       "235072,testing,some252f4,14084-things" 
[3] "224072,and,other2524,14084-thingies"    "223552,testing,some/2wr24,14084-things"
```

If your match occurs at the start or end of a string, `str_split()` will insert blank character entries in the results vector to indicate that (as it did above). If you don't need that information, you can easily remove it with `out[nchar(out) != 0]`.

```
[1] "235072,testing,some252f4,14084-things"  "224072,and,other2524,14084-thingies"   
[3] "223552,testing,some/2wr24,14084-things"
```

Answer (score 0):

With less complex regex, you can do as following:

```
s <- "235072,testing,some252f4,14084-things224072,and,other2524,14084-thingies223552,testing,some/2wr24,14084-things"
l <- str_locate_all(string = s, "[0-9]{6}")
str_sub(string = s, start = as.data.frame(l)$start, 
    end = c(tail(as.data.frame(l)$start, -1) - 1, nchar(s)) )
# [1] "235072,testing,some252f4,14084-things"
# [2] "224072,and,other2524,14084-thingies"
# [3] "223552,testing,some/2wr24,14084-things"
```